# How do I convert the following to if statements?

Tags: javascript

So I play a RPG on a Virtual Tabletop that supports API. I do not want to create a bunch of objects individually, so I am working with the API, and want to read attributes from a JSON dump and then write those attributes to a object in the game (Character). So all goes well with my code so far as long as I am pulling static info. But in the case of Skills, they may or may not have all of the attr defined, so NULL. I would like to be able to identifiy the null and move on, not fail out because it is NULL.

I have attached a GIST, I am a n00b to this, and I am a System Engineer in real life, but not a coder. So I would appreciate the input!

https://gist.github.com/bigdadmike/7548421

Above is all of my code, but specifically this is the section I am working on, these have all been declared as var at top of script. I have updated this post with comments and suggestions so far from Basti. Code:

```
on('ready', function() {

  _.each(monsterManual, function (monsterData){
  log(monsterData.Name);

var character = createObj('character', {
    name: monsterData.Name,
    gmnotes: monsterData.FullText,
});
//*/

_.each(monsterAttributes, function(attr) {
    var max = "";
    var cur = "";
    var re;

    switch(attr){
    case 'AC':
      cur = parseInt(monsterData[attr].match(/(\d+)/)[1]);
      break;
    case 'Str':
    case 'Dex':
    case 'Con':
    case 'Int':
    case 'Wis':
    case 'Cha':
      re = new RegExp(attr + "\\s*(\\d*).*");
      cur = parseInt(monsterData['AbilityScores'].match(re)[1]);
      break;
    case 'HD':
    case 'Size':
    case 'CR':
      cur = monsterData[attr];
      break;
    case 'HP':
      cur = parseInt(monsterData[attr]);
      max = cur;
      break;
    case 'BaseAtk':
      cur = parseInt(monsterData[attr]);
      max = cur;
      break;
    case 'CMB':
        cur = monsterData[attr];
        max = cur;
        break;
    case 'CMD':
        cur = parseInt(monsterData[attr]);
        max = cur;
        break;
case 'Acrobatics':
case 'Appraise':
case 'Bluff':
case 'Climb':
case 'Craft (any one)':
case 'Diplomacy':
case 'Disable Device':
case 'Disguise':
case 'Escape Artist':
case 'Fly':
    case 'Handle Animals':
    case 'Heal':
    case 'Intimidate':
    case 'Knowledge (religion)':
    case 'Knowledge (planes)':
    case 'Knowledge (history)':
    case 'Knowledge (nature)':
    case 'Knowledge (any one)': 
    case 'Linguistics':
    case 'Perception':
    case 'Ride':
    case 'Sense Motive':
    case 'Sleight of Hand':
    case 'Spellcraft':
    case 'Stealth':
    case 'Survival':
    case 'Swim':
    case 'Use Magic Device':
      re = RegExp(attr.replace('(', '\\(').replace(')', '\\)') + "\\s*(\\d*).*");
      var match = re.exec(monsterData['Skills'])
        if(match != null) {
            cur = parseInt(monsterData['Skills'].match(re)[1]);
            } 
            else {
            cur = 0;
            }
        break;
    default:
      cur = parseInt(monsterData[attr]);
      break;
    }

    log([attr, cur, max].join(':'))

    if(cur != 0) {
        createObj('attribute', {
            characterid: character.id,
            name: attr,
            max: max,
            current: cur
        });
    }
    //*/
});

});
});
```

Comment: This code is a great example of why you want to use `switch` over `if/else` in certain cases.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to achieve the results I am hoping for? I like the switch, and it is way cleaner than if statements but it is not functional once the data is not static. I have other portions of the JSON I want to incorporate as well, but it will present the same set of issues.

Comment: The part that stumps me is it keeps giving me a NAN issue when I have the skills portion enabled, once I comment out the skills all is good. I have reviewed in the JSON Object the SKILLS item and it appears much the same as the AbilityScores item. And I dont see NAN in any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically

```
switch(attr) {
    case 'AC':
      //...
      break;
    case 'Str':
    case 'Dex':
      //...
      break;
    //...
}
```

will be

```
if(attr == 'AC') {
  //...
} else if (attr == 'Str' || attr == 'Dex') {
  //...
}
```

and so on. A case following another case directly will be converted to an `or`-expression.

**BUT** as the comments already point out, this is - with regard to readabilty - a bad idea...

---

You want to change this code section:

```
case 'Use Magic Device':
  re = new RegExp(attr + "\\s*(\\d*).*");
  cur = parseInt(monsterData['Skills'].match(re)[1]);
  break;
```

to

```
case 'Use Magic Device':
  re = RegExp(attr.replace('(', '\\(').replace(')', '\\)') + "\\s*(\\d*).*");
  var match = re.exec(monsterData['Skills'])
  if(match != null) {
    cur = parseInt(match[1]);
  } else {
    cur = 0;
  }
  break;
```

This will check the match if it succeded (in this case the monster actually has the skill). If the match fails (the monst doesnt have this skill), then  there won't be a parsing error and the break lets you hop out of the switch.

Further down you want to encase the call to `createObject` with an if:

```
if(cur != 0) {
  createObj('attribute', {
      characterid: character.id,
      name: attr,
      max: max,
      current: cur
  });
}
```

Furthermore, in your `monsterAttributes` there are two spelling errors which will cause `cur` to get NaN:

```
var monsterAttributes = [
  /*...*/
  'Disguise ', //there's a whitespace after Disguise, remove it!
  /*...*/
  'Use Magic device', //the 'd' has to be capital, as you check on 'Use Magic Device'
  /*...*/
];
```

Comment: @BigMike try replacing `monsterData['Skills'].match(re)[1]` with just `match[1]`, but i doubt this will do the trick.

Comment: @BigMike found two spelling errors, see my answer again - i don't get any NaN-exceptions anymore

Comment: Awesome you totally rocked it!! Sometimes just another set of eyes is just what it takes! Thx for your awesome code suggestions and for the QA!

Comment: I want to merge functionality into this script form another script I had been working on that created the Player's Character Sheet. But it is confusing to me how I would go about merging them, specifically the auto creation of the Skill Macros... Any chance you would look at my newest question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you may simply check for attr being null and avoid the switch statement if this is the case.  For example:

```
if( attr != undefined && attr != null ){
  switch(attr){
    //... the code as is in here


  }// end switch
} // end if statement
```

Comment: Added it, but no difference in error: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null at evalmachine.<anonymous>:690:57 at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/symbly/www/d20-api-server/sandcastle/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:81:22) at evalmachine.<anonymous>:621:7 at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/symbly/www/d20-api-server/sandcastle/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:81:22) at Sandbox.<anonymous> (evalmachine.<anonymous>:612:5) at eval

Comment: is your RegEx correct? and it is correct for all cases evaluated by it? i.e. all the propreties from 'Acrobatics' to 'Use Magic Device'

Comment: I attached the GIST which has some of the JSON objects I am importing. I did a test originally with one, where I only defined the skills that it had in its "Skills" list. Used same code, no problem, problem starts when I put in multiplesand they have different skills, so some have skill A, some dont, some have skill b, some dont, etc...